# Using Teradata and python, getting SQL connection reset error with long running query - How can I page results?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query that selects many rows from a table using Teradata and Pythong ODBC.  The database does not allow long running queries, so I need my query to take less time per query.  (This is a rare exception case, normally the query returns instantly with say 1000 rows.) Once in every 10k instances of running the query I need it to return 70k rows, but when I try this, it is:

```
(<class 'pyodbc.Error'>, Error('08S01', '[08S01] [WSock32 DLL] 10054 WSA E Conn
Reset: Connection reset by peer (10054) (SQLPrepare)'), <traceback object at 0x0
14611C0>)
```

I think if I could limit the rows to 10k each, it would work fine during this strange condition.  Is there a way to do that?  I know how to do it in oracle:

```
select * 
from ( select a.*, rownum rnum
       from ( SELECT b.ind from item_sales b where b.cat=? ) a
      where rownum <= MAX_ROWS )
where rnum >= MIN_ROWS
```

But I do not know an equivalent in Teradata, since it does not have a rownumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in limitation in Teradata regarding runtime or size of answer set.

`Connection reset by peer` indicates the session was aborted, the DBA might have defined some rules in workload management, so I would approach them first.

Regarding paging, while there's no ROWNUM or LIMIT Standard SQLs ROW_NUMBER can do the same. But it needs unique ORDER BY column:

```
SELECT b.ind from item_sales b where b.cat=?
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) BETWEEN MIN_ROWS and MAX_ROWS
```

This is a stupid workaround if you actually need all rows, so better talk to your DBA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of the actual limitations of Teradata + PyODBC, but if you absolutely need to return the entire set of rows, would you be able to merge the data using multiple queries, (using returned PK IDs as references/pointers then merge the data into one, large datatable)?

If you simply need to limit the number of returned rows, in MySQL it should be something like:

```
SELECT col_name
FROM tbl_name
LIMIT 0,10000; //this returns rows 0-10,000 based on your choice of or lack of an ORDER BY clause
```

But then you need to know WHICH 10K rows to return, and if you know that, you should be able to write a view or stored procedure which returns a much more refined result set in the first place and query or execute that.

In my experience if you're timing out when requesting only 70K rows from a database, your query is inefficient and should be rewritten. Request the absolute minimum data you need in each step of the query and retrieve each column by name (e.g.: don't use "SELECT * FROM" use "SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C FROM", especially if your table contains a large number of columns or columns of type VARCHAR(MAX))

Comment: Yes, I would like to do something similar as the limit, but I can not do it in teradata.

Comment: Can you do it in a view then query the view?